# Team foundation server how to find a particular user's check-in only

Tags: visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server, source-control

In the **Source Control Explorer**, against a project by the **View History** I can see all the check-in done by the users.

In case if I want to see a particular user's check-in only, how can I filter?

Configurations: I'm using Team Foundation Server 2012 and Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to see a specific user's check-in only.

- In the Source Control Explorer click on the **Find Changesets** icon (**1** in the screenshot)
- In the popup, If you want to see the results for a specific project filer in the **Containing file: -> Browse** (**1.a** in the screenshot)
- In the **By user:**, type and Search or select the specific user from the dropdown list (**2** in the screenshot).
- You can add the conditions in the **Range:** for the changeset range or the created date, if doesn't require any filter, leave it with the **All changes**
- Now if you are click on the **Find** (**3** in the screenshot) button you can see the particular user's check-in only.

[image: user wise check-in]